# Problem with installing gtkada

Tags: software-installation, gtk, ada

Problem with installation of gtkada on x86_64-linux. Ubuntu version is 18.04.
I am installing it into a directory `$HOME/Ada` and everything is ok up to the `./configure` stage where I get  `error: old version found`. I did not want to disturb any old versions in case they were used by the system, so I'm not sure how to get round this error.

Steps in the process :

1. Downloaded the .tar file into `$HOME/Ada`.
2. Downloaded file `gnat-2021-20210519-x86_64-linux-bin` into `$HOME/Ada` and executed it, installing in the suggested directory `$HOME/opt/GNAT/2021`.
3. Extracted the files from the .tar file.
4. Included directories `$HOME/Ada`  and  `$HOME/opt/GNAT/2021` in `$PATH`.
5. Ran ./configure: `error: old version found`

Note  :  Environment variable  `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is empty (surprisingly).

Help on this will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu release/version?

Comment: changanAuto        Ubuntu 18.04